# Can 3-coloring be reduced to 3-clique?

Tags: np-complete, reductions, np

I'm a slight disagreement with my professor over whether or not a certain reduction is possible. He asked us to reduce the problem of 3-Coloring to the problem of 3-Clique. The problem is that I'm fairly confident that 3-Coloring is NP-Complete, while 3-Clique is P. Correct me if I'm wrong (which is very likely), but for any k-clique where the k is fixed, is $V^k$, meaning the 3-clique is $V^3$, right? I asked my professor about this and his response was:

"3-clique is definitely not in P.  You (apparently) have to examine all thrices of vertices to settle the matter."

And I still don't understand how this is not a $V^3$ operation.

If I figured out a way to reduce 3-coloring to 3-clique wouldn't I be millionaire?

Comment: I don't think it's fair to say it is a "slight disagreement" either. You have the right to a "full disagreement" since this is a factual question with an unambiguous yes/no answer. And it is clear that your professor does not actually understand what "NP-complete" means at all. And yes, you would be a millionaire if you reduced 3-colouring to 3-clique. =)

Comment: I'm not even convinced that you "have to examine all thrices of vertices", so it seems like there are multiple holes in your professor's argument, if you are representing it faithfully.

Comment: Sometimes a prof will assign a major unsolved problem, and once in a while someone will actually solve it without recognizing the extreme difficulty of doing so.  (Kind of a jerk move unless explicitly in the "bonus credit" category, but it happens, sometimes accidentally.)  Maybe the prof is hopeful that will happen in this class.

Comment: So the professor clarified in an email after I posted this. In the assignment description he asked for "3-clique" but after sending several emails back and forth and clarified that by "3-clique" he actually meant "3-clique cover" as in the algorithm that determines if a graph can be divided into 3 distinct cliques (which is NP-Complete). It was just a big miscommunication, but we got it worked out

Answer (score 5):

You are correct.

3-clique can be solved in $O(n^3)$ time, whereas 3-coloring is NP-hard.

So there can be no "poly-time reduction" from 3-coloring to 3-clique, unless $P=NP$.

Answer (score 3):

The number of k-tuples of vertices in a graph with $n$ vertices are: $^nC_k$. You can iterate through each possible k-tuple and check in $O(k^2)$ time whether the given k-tuple forms a clique. For **any fixed natural $k$**, the number $^nC_k$ is $O(n^k)$, and hence you can check whether a graph has $k$-clique in $O(k^{2}.{^n}C_k)$; the problem would be in $P$.

The problem of $k$-clique is $NP$-complete for arbitrary $k$.

Comment: So if I'm understanding your comment correctly, k-clique is NP-Complete if k is an input, but is P if K is a non variable natural number?

Comment: @exliontamer Yes, you can solve it in polynomial time for any fixed k, but it becomes hard if k is part of the input.

Comment: @exliontamer Just think what will happen if $k=n/2$. How many $k$-tuples of vertices are possible now?